# Single WCF Service with Multiple Business Objects Implementaion

Tags: c#, wcf

Suppose I have 2 interfaces & a single WCF Service ( MyService1 ) in one project:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]    
    interface IOrders
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void GetOrders();
        /*Some more methods here */
    }


[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]    
    interface ICustomers
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void GetCustomer();
        /*Some more methods here */
    }
```

If I add a reference of above project in one of my application (be it a WinForm/Web ),

**How Should I structure/Write the MyService1 implementation as so that I can access Members as :**

```
MyService1 svc = new MyService1() ;

svc.Orders.GetOrders();
svc.Customers.GetCustomer();
```

**EDIT:** 
I tried this :

```
 public class MyService1  : IOrders,ICustomers
 {
  public  void GetOrders()
  {
   // some thing..
  }
  public void GetCustomer()
  {

  }       
}
```

But this does not help as the output for above is :

```
MyService1 svc = new MyService1() ;
svc.GetOrders();
svc.GetCustomer();
```

Comment: Cast it to `IOrders` or `ICustomers`?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.. can u please demonstrate via some code. I am looking out for starting point..

Comment: What have you tried, what errors do you get? Adding this information will get you better answers, right now your question is "Please help me write code"

Comment: But why you need `svc.Orders.GetOrders()` and `svc.Customers.GetCustomer()` instead of `svc.GetOrders()` and `svc.GetCustomers()`?

Comment: I have multiple business objects Orders, Customers, Employees etc & the requirement is to expose them via a single wcf service. thus the need for categorization..